# Get text separetly

Tags: jquery

I have following html

```
<div>
   <span>123</span>
   <span>456<span>789</span></span>
</div>
```

When I try to get text it gives in one line

```
 $('div').text()  ---> '123456789'
```

**Question:** How to get text separetly like:

```
123 456 789
```

Comment: Use `$('div *')` instead of `$('div span')`

Comment: Thanks, It works although it outputs '123' '456789' '789'. I will use some conditions to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check every element in `div`, if it hasn't child get it text and if has child, go to it child and get text of them.

```js
var text = "";
function getText(element){
    $(element).children().each(function(index){
        var child = $(this).children();
       if (child.length == 0)
           text += "," + $(this).text().trim();           
       else {
            text += "," + child[0].previousSibling.nodeValue.trim();
            getText(this);
        }
    });
}

getText($("div"));
console.log(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <span>123</span>
   <span>
       456
       <span>789</span>
   </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this is final answer

Answer (score 2):

For getting text separately, you need to loop through all span and get its text:

```
$('div span').each(function(){
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: What if elements are nested?

Comment: @doniyor Refer the below answer for nested elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this also,

**HTML:**

```
<div>
   <p>this is vignesh
     <span>chinnaiyan</span>
   </p>
   <span>I</span>
   <h1>LOVE</h1>
   <span>PHP</span>
</div>
<div id="result">

</div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
 var spantext = ""; 
 $('div span').each(function()
 {
     spantext =  spantext +" "+$(this).text();
     $("#result").html(spantext);
 });
```

**Output:**

this is vignesh chinnaiyan chinnaiyan I LOVE PHP

Fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/xo88rnk1/